# Adjust volume of audio stream using AudioUnitSetParameter not works

Tags: ios, core-audio, audio-streaming, audiounit

```
AudioUnitSetParameter(appBufferContext->unit, kDynamicsProcessorParam_MasterGain, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, 0.5 , 0);
```

This line returns -50. What is the meaning of it? Actually I want to adjust volume of steamed Audio packets.

Answer (score 0):

You have invoked this method with a bad/invalid parameter (kAudio_ParamError == An error in the parameter list of the function). Without knowing more about your graph, I recommend first double checking your Scopes and elements, per: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1438454-audiounitsetparameter?language=occ

For example, is your `scope == kAudioUnitScope_Output` correct, what about the `element == 0`?

If you don't know, use [CAShow()](https://sites.google.com/site/iphonecoreaudiodevelopment/home/debugging-the-augraph) to debug your graph, so you can see exactly how components are wired up.

In the future, you can check CoreAudio error codes here:
https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-50